# Why does int count jump from 1 to 4 on entering a loop? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, counter, increment

My "counter" is jumping from 1 to 4 when I enter my loop. Any ideas? Code and output below:

```
    static bool harvestLog()
{
    ifstream myFile("LOGS/ex090716.log");
    if (myFile.fail()) {cout << "Error opening file";return 1;}
    else
    {
        cout << "File opened... \n";
        string line;
        string field;
        int cs_uri_stemLocation = 0;
        int csReferrerLocation = 0;
        int count = 1;
        cout << "-" << count << "-";
        while( getline(myFile, line) ) {
            if ( strstr(line.c_str(), "cs-uri-stem") &&
                (strstr(line.c_str(), "cs(Referer)") || strstr(line.c_str(), "cs(Referrer)")) )
            {
                cout << "-" << count << "-";
                cout << "Found log format: \n";
                istringstream foundField(line);
                while (!foundField.eof())
                {
                    cout << "-" << count << "-";
                    foundField >> field;
                    if (field == "cs-uri-stem") {cs_uri_stemLocation = count;}
                    if (field == "cs(Referer)" || field == "cs(Referrer)") {csReferrerLocation = count;}
                    cout << "cs-uri-stem: " << cs_uri_stemLocation << ". ";
                    cout << "cs(Referer): " << csReferrerLocation << ". ";
                    cout << "COUNT: " << count << endl;
                    count++;
                }
                cout << "Found field cs-uri-stem at position " << cs_uri_stemLocation << "." << endl;
                cout << "Found field cs(Referer) at position " << csReferrerLocation << "." << endl;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 1;
                istringstream foundField(line);
                while (!foundField.eof())
                {
                    foundField >> field;
                    //if (count == cs_uri_stemLocation) cout << field << endl;
                    count++;
                }

                //cmatch results;
                //regex rx("(?:p|q)(?:=)([^ %]*)");
                //regex_search(line.c_str(), results, rx);
                //string referringWords = results[1];

                //cout << referringWords;
            }
        }
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
    }
}
```

> -1--4-Found log format:
>   -4-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 4
>   -5-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 5
>   -6-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 6
>   -7-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 7
>   -8-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 8
>   -9-cs-uri-stem: 0. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 9
>   -10-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 10
>   -11-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 11
>   -12-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 12
>   -13-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 13
>   -14-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 14
>   -15-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 0. COUNT: 15
>   -16-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 16. COUNT: 16
>   -17-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 16. COUNT: 17
>   -18-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 16. COUNT: 18
>   -19-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 16. COUNT: 19
>   -20-cs-uri-stem: 10. cs(Referer): 16. COUNT: 20
>   Found field cs-uri-stem at position 10.
>   Found field cs(Referer) at position 16.

Comment: Tried LogParser? http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Comment: Want to write my own actually. With a little added functionality ;-)

Comment: Looks like you're missing the end brace on your while loop.  Do you close it right after the if statement or is there more to the while loop?

Comment: Sorry about that, the whole function is there now.

Comment: Which loop?  I see more than one with counters.  For the best answers, you should trim code until you can't get the odd behavior any more, and post the exact code.  Few people will be interested in wading through a long stretch of code that can't even be copied out and compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would bet that it's going throught the

```
                        while (!foundField.eof())
                        {
                                foundField >> field;
                                //if (count == cs_uri_stemLocation) cout << field << endl;
                                count++;
                        }
```

and you never reset it after this branch

Answer (score 1):

Can't you attach a debugger and step through the code? It doesn't look like you are going to have many iterations to go through to see the answer. (If this Visual Studio you could set a data break point on count at just hit run. I suspect GDB and most other debuggers will also support this.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided all code in your loop - there's an unmatched open curly brace after the while statement. Do you have some cout code below what you've extracted?

Comment: I apologize, I have now included the entire function. I was trying to narrow in on the problem, but it's not worth the trouble caused by lacking externalities.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your if statement right after the while loop begins comes back false?  The else attached to that if contains a count++ statement in a loop.